# append guid to hyperlink using xslt

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I have some xml being returned in sharepoint,
Im using xslt to create the hyperlink like so.

```
<a href="{substring-before(Sign-up-Link,',')}">
    Sign up for event
</a>
```

I also have an element `<guid>1234</guid>` being returned in the xml,
an I'd like it so that the link will be with the guid appended as a querystring

e.g. http://www.foo.com/signup.aspx?guid=1234

how do i append the guid?

thanks

Comment: Please, provide the smallest posible XML document, so that it would be possible to construct an XPath expression that selects "guid". Just saying "I also have an element <guid>1234</guid> being returned in the xml" is not helpful. See my answer for one possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="{substring-before(Sign-up-Link,',')}?guid={XPathExpression---Selecting---The---GUID}">
    Sign up for event
</a>
```

**As the actual XML document is not shown, we cannot guess what XPath expression to use in order to select it**.

Therefore, In the `href` attribute of the above literal result element, the second AVT (attribute-value-template) contains just a placeholder for this XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

Depends where the guid appears in the xml but I would imagine concat() would do the trick e.g.

```
<a href="{concat(substring-before(Sign-up-Link,','),'?guid=',guid)}"/>
```

Comment: Why do you think that "Sign-up-Link" has a sibling named "guid"? The problem says: "I also have an element <guid>1234</guid> being returned in the xml" ...  Most vague description. Also, the concat() function is not really needed -- see my answer.

Comment: Yes it's vague that's whay I said it depends where the guid elements appears in the xml, my assumption of sibling position is for illustration purposes

Answer (score 1):

```
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                {substring-before(Sign-up-Link,',')}?guid=
                <xsl:value-of select="@guid">
                </xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                SignUpLink
            </xsl:attribute>
            Sign Up
        </a>
```

That might work...

Comment: THis will not produce the required result. The problem says that the "guid" is an element somewhere in the xml document -- not an attribute of the parent of "Sign-up-Link"